# Single-pane to Two-pane

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I'm working on a Android project and got a problem with the two-pane layout (list + detail).

Current state:

- Working two-pane layout (like in GMail-App) for screens with larger width than 600dp and landscape orientation.
- Switching from two-pane to single-pane layout works
- Working single-pane layout for devices with smaller width than 600dp in any orientation.

Problem:

If the user(device screen width larger than 600dp) is in portrait-mode and selects a list item the detail view popups up (which is correct). If the user now changes orientation to landscape the layout should change to two-pane layout with the list and the selected detail view. But the app stays in the single-pane layout.

In my opinion the problem is caused because I start a new activity in single-pane mode instead of exchanging some fragments. But i really don't know how to achieve this.

The following code shows what happens if the user selects a list item.

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AndroidCalendar calendar) {
    if (mTwoPane) {
        // two-pane mode
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putSerializable(CalendarDetailFragment.CALENDAR, calendar);
        CalendarDetailFragment fragment = new CalendarDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(arguments);
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.calendaritem_detail_container, fragment)
                .commit();

    } else {
        // single-pane mode
        Intent detailIntent = new Intent(this, CalendarDetailActivity.class);
        detailIntent.putExtra(CalendarDetailFragment.CALENDAR, calendar);
        startActivity(detailIntent);
    }
```

For example the Boxer app (EMail) and gReader supports this behavior. I think GMail app too.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your desired behavior by using the navigation drawer scheme for your app. Since ultimatly the two parts of the layout (The drawer and the detail) are both fragments you can have one layout just work like a normal navigation drawer where it slides back and forth. Then in your tablet layout make the fragment not slide and just be permanently visible. In your main activity you can implement logic to see the screen size and deduce if its a tablet or not. Then you'll have a dynamic layout without having to create different activities.

I'd also check out [this](http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/adaptui.html) guide.